# How can I set the mousewheel scroll to work on the component with focus and not the component where the mouse pointer is over?

Tags: c#, scroll, components, focus, windows-forms-designer

I have a windows form application and I have a problem that when I'm scrolling on a panel and the mouse pointer go over another component (usually a child), that may or may not have a scroll, the panel stops scrolling. If this component has a scroll then this component will start scrolling.
I want to set the mouse wheel to only scroll the component that has Focus, not the one that the mouse pointer is over, but I cant make it work...
Is it possible to make this happen?
Thanks.

EDIT: I recently noticed that in web applications when you are scrolling down and your mouse hovers above another component with a scroll in it, it doesn't change the target of the scroll until you move your mouse inside the other component or you keep the mouse still for a few seconds. If it's possible to implement something like this in Windows Form it would be a perfect solution.

Comment: This is a Windows option (which used to be off by default, but now seems to be on by default?) https://www.groovypost.com/howto/scroll-inactive-background-windows-by+hovering-over-them/

Comment: I tried changing the setting and it worked... so this is a setting of the Windows and not the application. But since this is something that the user is complaining about and I can't ask him to change his Windows settings, is there any way that I can make this work only in the application?

Comment: You can't easily make it work this way in just your application, without implementing a global hook of mouse messages so you can intercept the scroll messages being sent to windows that your application doesn't own.

Comment: I see why this would be difficult but the main complain we are receiving is that when the user is scrolling he is constantly being stuck in components that the mouse hovers over so he needs to move the mouse out of the component to keep scrolling. So we don't necessarily need to intercept the scroll being done outside the application.